# MySQL - One to Many relationship - Boolean Search

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL tables that look like this -

- Candidate - id, name
- Skills - id, name
- CandSkills - candid, skillid

Now I am trying to fetch all candidates who have "Java" as a skill and "Salesforce" as a skill. In this case following query works out well -

```
select cs.candid from CandSkills cs inner join Skills s on (cs.skillid = s.id) 
group by cs.candid where s.name in ('Java', 'Salesforce') 
having count(s.name) = 2
```

Now the thing is, that the skills to search for is provided by a user from a web UI via ajax call. So it can be any combination or "and"/"or". For example, user can search for candidates with skills -

- Java and Salesforce - get candidates who have both `Java` and `Salesforce`
- MySQL or PHP and Nodejs - get candidates who have both `MySQL` and `Nodejs`, or have `PHP` only
- AngularJs and Salesforce or PHP or Denodo and Java - get candidates who have all 3 `AngularJs`, `Salesforce` and `Java` or have both `PHP` and `Denodo`

The above query with count approach does not work for all the cases (case 2, 3 above) -

```
select cs.candid from CandSkills cs inner join Skills s on (cs.skillid = s.id) 
    group by cs.candid where s.name in ('MySQL', 'Nodejs', 'PHP') 
    having count(s.name) = 2
```

This might return candidates who have MySQL and PHP, but not Nodejs.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

PS - MySQL version is 5.4, so FULLTEXT search in boolean mode is not there for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this once and the only way I was able to do it (without Oracle SQL) was something like this. I'm not sure about it's performance, but I think the sql engine could do some some heavy optimizing on this so it might perform well.

*** Warning it's kind of cancer to look at.**

```
select cs.candid
from CandSkills cs 
inner join Skills s1 on (cs.skillid = s1.id AND s1.name = 'MySQL' )
inner join Skills s2 on (cs.skillid = s1.id AND s1.name = 'Nodejs' ) 
inner join Skills s3 on (cs.skillid = s1.id AND s1.name = 'PHP' )
```

You can also use exists instead of inner joins.

Comment: How will it take care of OR condition for PHP? I think this will return all the candidates who have all 3 - mysql, nodejs and php. Am I right?

Comment: You would have to group the joins or add it to the join condtions

Comment: +1 for warning ! My current Skills table has more than 4 million entries for 600K candidates. This is expected to grow and reach 600 million in skills table in 2 years.